# .m3u8 based video still has severe buffering issues on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, streaming, video-streaming

I'm working on getting a streaming video solution implemented for a client, with iOS devices targeted (mostly iPad).

I have diced up my video files into TS's and I have my accompanying m3u8 file. They are being hosted by a generic web host, and CDN'd by Amazon CloudFront, so on paper speed should be fine.

I am noticing that pretty much no matter what, the iPad is still having substantial buffering problems at pre-determined points (presumably where one segment ends and another begins).

My lowest bitrate for the TS files is 600kb/s which seems like that would be plenty low for typical WiFi streaming, but it still stops pretty hard.

I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong... I don't think it's the file hosting... as once it STARTS downloading, it goes fast. I feel like perhaps my m3u8 is somehow incomplete or inadequate...

As a side note, these videos are only 30-35 seconds long, and the media segmenter slices them into 3-4 pieces.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out any solution to this? I've been trying to stream an m3u8 file through both AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController and I am having consistent playback issues.